# How to discover a Java Class Path used by LoadJavaClass?

Tags: java

How can I discover which path is read to load some Java class using the command: `LoadJavaClass["my.java.class"]`?

I believe all `JavaClassPath[]` is scanned, but which is used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2023-06-16: It is reported that the following response no longer works when using *Mathematica 13.2* on MacOS.**

The following function can be used to recover the resource URL that contains a given class:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[];
LoadJavaClass["com.wolfram.jlink.JLinkClassLoader"];

classResourceUrl[className_] :=
  JavaBlock @ Module[{resourceName, loader}
  , resourceName = StringReplace[className, "."->"/"]~~".class"
  ; loader =
      com`wolfram`jlink`JLinkClassLoader`classFromName[className] @ getClassLoader[] /.
        Null :> com`wolfram`jlink`JLinkClassLoaderHelper`getSystemClassLoader[]
  ; loader@getResource[resourceName] /. url:Except[Null] :> url@toString[]
  ]
```

It works by:

1. Using `JLinkClassLoader` to recover the Java class object.
2. Getting the class' classloader (`Null` indicating the system classloader).
3. Using that classloader to get the URL of the class' binary name.

Here it is in action:

```
classResourceUrl["org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"]

(* jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Wolfram%20Research/Mathematica/10.2/
   SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/hsqldb.jar!
   /org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCDriver.class *)

classResourceUrl["org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine"]

(* jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Wolfram%20Research/Mathematica/10.2/
   SystemFiles/Links/RLink/Java/JRI.jar!
   /org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.class *)

AddToClassPath @ "C:\\eclipse\\plugins\\org.junit_4.10.0\\junit.jar";
classResourceUrl["org.junit.Assert"]

(* jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.10.0/junit.jar!
   /org/junit/Assert.class *)
```

Comment: This is very useful. Tks +1

Comment: Thanks. This was useful to diagnose conflicts!

Comment: I do not think this solution works anymore. (At least on macOS.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks for the info.  Unfortunately, I no longer have access to recent versions of _Mathematica_ so I can take this no further.  If you can say which version(s) you know are broken, I can put a disclaimer at the top of the response.

Comment: I used Mathematica version 13.2 on macOS. (Thanks!)